# Triggers on views

Tags: sql-server, database

Can we write triggers on view in sql server. If yes when will these triggers get fired? 
Suppose i write an insert trigger on the view, will it fire when i insert data into the base table from which the view has been built?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can create triggers on views. (Since at least [SQL Server 2000](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).)

If you create a trigger on a view, it won't fire on inserts to the base table. If you want something to happen when you insert data into a base table, create a trigger on the base table.

You can create an INSTEAD OF trigger on a view, and have that trigger insert data into a base table.

How hard is it to test that in your own schema?